# Can't puts parameter from yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yield

Why I can't puts parameter from yield?

Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `options' for #<#<Class:0x007fd1bd8735e8>:0x007fd1ba3e4fe8>
```

/app/helpers/bootstrap_form_helper.rb

```
...
  def inline
    options = "row_disable"
    content_tag(:div, class: "row test") { yield(options) }
  end
...
```

/app/views/signup/new.html.erb

```
...    
<%= inline do %>
  <%= options %>
  <%= person_f.text_field(:last_name, control_col: 7) %>
<% end %>
...
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: As a result, I try to pass this variable in the text_field. But at first, I can't puts it in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the **local variable**, `options`, defined in the `inline` method. You have to access the **argument** passed to the block by the `inline` method, and to do that you need to have your block in new.html.erb accept an `options` argument:

```
  ...    
  <%= inline do |options| %>
    <%= options %>
    <%= person_f.text_field(:last_name, control_col: 7) %>
  <% end %>
  ...
```

Just to clarify a little further, you don't even need to call it `options` in new.html.erb. The following would also work:

```
  ...    
  <%= inline do |foo| %>
    <%= foo %>
    <%= person_f.text_field(:last_name, control_col: 7) %>
  <% end %>
  ...
```